# How to make graphical login not wait for network?

Tags: boot, 16.04, systemd, smb

How can I make it so that graphical login shows up before/asynchronously of network configuration? I have to use DHCP, and sometimes the DHCP server dies in subtle ways, leading to significantly longer boot times.

Compared to a fresh install it seems that `smbd.service` pulled network into the critical chain. The only network thing I have in fstab is `//sh/are /m/p cifs noauto,x-systemd.automount`.

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain

graphical.target @10.231s
└─multi-user.target @10.231s
  └─smbd.service @10.126s +105ms
    └─nmbd.service @9.911s +205ms
      └─network-online.target @9.892s
        └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.075s +8.816s
          └─NetworkManager.service @855ms +79ms
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling [NetworkManager-wait-online.service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018731/307523)?

Comment: Per the other commenter, the top-upvoted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do) *directly* solves your issue.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude fascinating!
Closed in favor.