# Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online

Tags: boot

When I try to boot Ubuntu on my laptop (that's dual boot with windows 10) I get `Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online` and the shut down process begins and my laptop shuts down without booting into Ubuntu. The only way I can boot is through recovery mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode, open a terminal and use:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

This will allow you to reboot in normal mode.

More [details about this service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do).