# kernel = 2min boot with SSD

Tags: boot, network-manager, performance, systemd

I'm an intern and try to find out why our system is booting slowly.
My Ubuntu/Linux knowledge is limited (6 months of private experience with WSL).

Workstation, SSD, no dual boot, Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 1min 53.217s (kernel) + 8.170s (userspace) = 2min 1.388s
```

Blame option showed NetworkManager-wait-online.service with 7.099s (all other services in ms range) and [this forum suggested I simply disable the service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do). I don't know if I should, I don't wanna mess things up.  Also I'm not sure if it's a network boot. How can I check this?

```bsh
~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        823M        5.4G        169M        1.5G        6.4G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
```

```bsh
~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0e
       serial: b8:ae:ed:ff:93:2f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=129.132.113.166 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:ec00(size=256) memory:df218000-df218fff memory:df210000-df213fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 59
       serial: 48:45:20:af:4e:75
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-43-generic firmware=17.352738.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:131 memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 06
       serial: f4:f2:6d:06:6d:1b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df000000-df000fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
```

```bsh
~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0 230.1G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Might this be of any help? <https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do> A very good explanation and a possible fix for a common delay problem.

Comment: Do you connect to the Internet via wireless or ethernet? Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. What does "working with it under Win10" mean? Are you using VirtualBox or WSL?

Comment: Do you have separate Filesystems for "/" and "/usr"? With 18.04 it is important to have "/usr" as a directory in "/".

Comment: @GrumpyBurger that's the thread I was refering to in my question. As described I wanted to check with this forum if this will have any negative consequences first and whether it has to access some company server first (they guy I could ask is absent)

Comment: @heynnema edited question. The Desktop PC uses ethernet. (WSL is not problem related. I was just explaining where I got my Linux experience from)

Comment: @WiglafPimwick not sure if this answers your question but "/usr" exists

Comment: After cold boot `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`  maybe entropy problem.

Comment: @nobody entropy output is 2001. I looked that up before due to a splash message that caught my eye and moving the mouse around during boot saved like 10s

Comment: `sudo dmesg -T` please paste it here  https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Remove the eth1 ethernet card, and see if it boots up faster. Report back.

Comment: I just noticed that your eth0 ethernet device is not working at 1Gb, which means that it may not be plugged into a gigabit router/switch/modem, or you're using the incorrect/bad ethernet cable. It should be a cat 5E or cat 6 cable. Comments?

Comment: @nobody https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zWQ3g3gHyY/

Comment: @heynnema indeed an ethernet cable communicates with a control box for the device the company manufactures. However this control box is not powered on while booting. Advice on how to check which eth is which?

Comment: @VI6 Yes. If the control box is powered off, then look for the green/yellow blinking LED near where the ethernet cable plugs into the port. The blinking one is eth0, and the other is eth1. Two issues to solve then... For eth1, power on the control box and see if the boot time is much shorter. For eth0, check your cables, and make sure it's all connected to a gigabit switch/router/modem. Report back.