# Move a service out of the critical boot chain?

Tags: boot, systemd, performance

I'm tired of services such as `snapd` and `blueman-mechanism` delaying my boot by upwards of 10, 20 seconds each on Ubuntu 20.04.4.

While the solution for snapd was simply to `apt purge` it, I don't like the idea of [crippling my machine's hardware capabilities](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1879001&sid=3b363778fb2167bedd58a6e38a410183#p1879001), as I've been considering getting a bluetooth headset or keyboard recently—that's just not a reasonable workaround.

It it possible to leave certain services enabled, but **remove them from the boot-wait chain**?

Even on my laptop, there's no reason that the system should, for example, block me from logging in for an additional 4.068s while waiting for `wpa_supplicant.service` to start up, much less on a desktop (which I pulled that particular number from in this instance—it's highlighted in deep red in the SVG plot) with no currently-active Wi-Fi connections.

Right now, it seems the options are

- Just cope / buy more hardware upgrades (that will be obsolete in a few years anyway)
- Start disabling parts of the system *that I might legitimately need later* as a workaround for inappropriate boot dependencies

Is there any way to avoid both of these depressing options and simply *remove* certain services from the boot-wait chain (but without disabling them)? I'd much rather have `networkd-dispatcher.service` (10.093s) keep chugging *while* I'm typing my password and logging in.

For some services, such as `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` (9.897s), disabling them is [generally viable for user-facing desktops](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018731/95681)… but I'm interested in **fixing** the problem—safely transplanting services *out* of the boot wait chain—rather than continuing to play whack-a-mole with unique components and hoping I don't break something. The only things I need ready *before* I log in are the filesystem check and the display and input drivers. Everything else can share CPU with Firefox.

Comment: We've had multi-core CPUs for how many years now? Send that stuff to another thread! Even my backup machine's Pentium 4 has hyperthreading. Why _have_ a pre-empting kernel if we're not going to _use_ it?

Comment: Some preliminary analysis shows a few highly problematic chains: (1) `lightdm.service` is `After` `systemd-user-sessions.service` which is `After` `network.target`; (2) `graphical.target` is `After` `multi-user.target` which is `After` `wpa_supplicant.service NetworkManager.service systemd-networkd.service` and `Wants` `blueman-mechanism.service`

Comment: Annoyingly, systemd [does not let](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) one override these relationships easily: “Dependencies (`After=`, etc.) cannot be reset to an empty list \[in overrides\]… **If you want to remove dependencies, you have to override the entire unit.**”