# Can disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` be considered harmful? What are alternatives?

Tags: boot, 22.04, startup, systemd, boot-time

My computer spends ~5s of startup time waiting for the wifi[1].
[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018731/47300) promotes disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`, and this works indeed. However, I was wondering if this may introduce other problems?

I find it quite sensical that programs may wawnt to wait for wifi to connect. But I don't want the main system to depend on those. Is it possible to somehow get rid of this dependency, without disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`?

---

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @7.982s
└─multi-user.target @7.982s
  └─kerneloops.service @7.968s +13ms
    └─network-online.target @7.964s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.580s +6.384s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.498s +57ms
          └─dbus.service @1.494s
            └─basic.target @1.473s
              └─sockets.target @1.473s
                └─snapd.socket @1.472s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.464s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @1.215s +244ms
                      └─apparmor.service @1.136s +73ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.134s
                          └─run-user-1000.mount @7.909s
                            └─swap.target @1.067s
                              └─dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap @1.059s +7ms
                                └─dev-mapper-vgkubuntu\x2dswap_1.device @1.055s
```