24.04 installed. wifi not working. will not authenticate with wifi router
i installed 24.04 on my acer laptop.  all networks in my home clearly show connectivity under system settings.  when attempting to logon, authentication password required window appears.  I entered the router password not connection. copy pasted password; no connection.  I have wired connections. Searched for device in terminal per other articles.  pci qualcomm atheros adapter appears in list; usb appears in list.  please help.  i need my laptop wireless for school and work.  could not find driver.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is your phone able to used wifi from the router?

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please see the answers to this question about what information is needed to diagnose wifi problems.. Then, please edit your question to include a pastebin link to the output of the wireless-info script. This should give us all the information needed to diagnose the issue. Thanks.

All devices in my home and cell phone can connect to wifi.  Appears i can receive signal from all networks close to me.  Cannot send password authentication to my router from ubuntu.   Tried reboot,  updates,  ls commands...can see pci adapter.

Thnx.  I am new to linux.  Please provide detail instruction and command to run for wieless activity script.  I will provide paste information asap.

I am having the same problem and have an open question. I have worked around it by manually entering IP address, netmask, gateway and dns server in the wireless connection settings (Settings>Network). You might also have to select the BSSID and MAC address. Manual configuration will get you up and running, but it is no fix.
Added: 2024-06-03
In my case the problem is being caused by apparmor. I have confirmed this by disabling the dhclient profile in /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient as follows:

cd /etc/apparmor.d

If there is no disable directory create it as follows:

sudo mkdir /etc/apparmor.d/disable

Create a link to the sbin.dhclient profile in the new disable directory:

sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient /etc/apparmor.d/disable

The profile is currently loaded and so needs to be disabled:

sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient

Obviously this is not a permanent solution, and I know nothing about apparmor, so I will raise a more specific question about apparmor and how to modify the profile so that dhclient works correctly when called by NetworkManager.

New ths forum .  Answered question.  Response too long.  Can use all other devices in my home via wifi.  Can see all wifi networks close to my home.  Wifi password not working.  Ls commands show pci device qualcomm atheros. Tried wps..fail.  window saying password or token required.  One other answer i will try re..app armor.  New to linux.  Reponse suhhestio with detail would be most appreciate.

Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516174/wifi-not-connecting-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-problem-with-apparmor?noredirect=1#comment2662247_1516174 regarding disabling apparmor profile for dhclient

apparmor work around failed.  :

fwupd-refresh.service                           loaded failed failed  Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd

tried copy and paste in terminal...too many characters to provide entire script.  please assist by providing a way to copy entire message from terminal to post.   thanks.  note attempted ctr shift c.

i have revisited the instructions you provided.  i do not know why, or how, my wifi is working   best wishes and thank you so much,  i am so happy to get back to work using wifi.

Good news. I delved deeper into my problem with apparmor and found the reason and a solution on the link above. It's quite complicated and my rule is if it's not broken don't fix it, so I would ignore this if I were you. If you think my answer helped, please uprate it because it might help others with the same or similar problems.

Thnx gary.  New to forym.  How can i uprate you.  I do not have enough credits or points to vote apparently.   Let me know.  Have a great day.

Just click on the up-arrow next to the answer, but only if you think the answer deserves it. I am quite new to this myself.
